# How to print mysql column names to a file

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How to print out MySQL table field names and types or 
how to save the MySQL table field names to a text file? 
is it possible. (front end VB.NET 2010)

Eg:- `SHOW COLUMNS FROM tablename;`
how can I get the above command result to a printer or a file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
Dim cn As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
Dim rdr As OleDbDataReader
Dim tbl As DataTable

cmd.CommandText = "Select * From " & TableName
cn.Open()
cmd.Connection = cn
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly Or
CommandBehavior.KeyInfo)
tbl = rdr.GetSchemaTable  // Read tbl and Write it to text file

rdr.Close()
```

Hope this will help.